# Library for using SVG in Windows Forms / WPF?

Tags: xaml, svg, inkscape

Are there any libraries which

1. Allow to draw svg direct to a Windows Forms application
2. to a WPF application

I draw graphics and design everything with [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org), because I love that program.
Then I have those stunning svgs and have to either export them to png (WinForm) to use them or convert them to xaml-code (WPF) ([Kaxaml](http://www.kaxaml.com/) helps me).

Is there a way to directly use my svgs?

Answer (score 10):

**Wow**, I [just read](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/10/inkscape-to-support-xaml-export.aspx) that Inkscape supports saving as XAML. I didn't realize that up to now *shame*.

But that still doesn't solve my problems with WinForms...

Comment: unfortunately it is not yet ready, it is going to be implemented and hopefully it will be out with version 0.47 of Inkscape

Comment: Save as XAML is implemented in 0.48 (possibly earlier).

Answer (score 7):

I personally hate how there's no native support for SVG in Microsoft's products/development tools. I've found two fairly complete but still immature SVG libraries that seem to be active as of this writing, definitely in need of contributors though.

- **WPF** : [Svg2Xaml (open source)](http://svg2xaml.codeplex.com/)
- **WinForms** : [SVG rendering engine (open source)](http://svg.codeplex.com)

IIRC both libraries output a Drawing object which can be used directly through the Image class; You'll figure it out, they're both pretty straightforward to use.

Comment: I want to add this tool to the list: https://github.com/BerndK/SvgToXaml
I wrote it, because I wasn't satisfied with the other tools, sure it is also open source.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to load them directly into WPF,
I got better results from: https://github.com/ElinamLLC/SharpVectors

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use [ReaderSVG](https://www.ab4d.com/ReaderSvg.aspx) from AB4D to get WPF directly from XAML.

Regarding WinForms, removed a previous link to Kent Boogart's example as it was deleted sometime in 2019.

Copy below from [this dotnetways post](http://dotnetways.blogspot.com/2010/10/host-wpf-controls-in-windows-forms.html)

To host a WPF control or WPF user control (wpfControl in this example) into Windows Form application, create an instance of ElementHost Class and add your WPF control/user control as child to the instance of ElementHost.

```cs
    using System.Windows.Forms.Integration;   
    //Assembly:   WindowsFormsIntegration (in WindowsFormsIntegration.dll) 

//...

    ElementHost elementHost = new ElementHost();  
    elementHost.Dock = DockStyle.None;  
    elementHost.Child = wpfControl;
```

Now, add the instance of ElementHost to a container control in your windows form (for instance containerPanel here)

```cs
    containerPanel.Controls.Add(elementHost);
```

Comment: dead links fixed